SMBLibrary listshares returning count 0
I have been trying to connect to SMB server using SMBlibrary in my winform application. Below is my code
SMB2Client client = new SMB2Client(); // SMB2Client can be used as well
bool isConnected = client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("172.31.2.11"), SMBTransportType.DirectTCPTransport);
if (isConnected)
{
    NTStatus status = client.Login(string.Empty, "", "");
    
    if (status == NTStatus.STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        var ls = client.ListShares(out status);
        var treeId = client.TreeConnect("Test99", out status);
    }
    client.Disconnect();
}

I am able to connect to the SMB server successfully but when i try to get the listshares, i get count 0. Also the treeconnect is returning null. There are shared folder inside the SMB server.
I have tried to connect multiple shared folder using treeconnect but everytime i get null value returned.
